# Not able to locate element with Xpath

Tags: python, xpath, webdriver

Here is the deal, i have some sinopses to take out from the IMDB website, but the sinopse element is inside a box without anything to track (Like the following image) , i was trying like this, but i don't know how to extract the text, get_attribute or something like this.

THAT'S THE WORKING VERSION

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2731500/')

alo = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@itemprop="description"]').text
print(alo)
```

[The image of the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixl1U.png)

Comment: please read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Save the html to disk

2) get an xml tool like xmllint and a bunch of good tutorials on XPath.

3) Test and debug your XPath until you find the solution.

4) If you have concrete questions about XPath, ask them here.

let's say the element you are interested in is

```
<div class="summary_text" itemprop="description">
        This documentary highlights the role of education professionals in the Second Republic of Spain as the first independent and free women who broke with the female prototype of that era.
</div>
```

So the xpath could be

`//div[@itemprop="description"]`

or for the english version of the page

`//div[@itemprop="description"]/p/text()`

Comment: That's the part you are intersted in? Add it to your question.

Comment: The thing is, i'm not being able to get the element from the Xpath i made, when i put .get_attribute(), it returns saying that it needs a "name", when i put .get_attribute(0) it says that the result is "none".

Comment: ok. On the browser, right click on the element you are interested in and see if it has an id. Try to use it in your xpath. And getAttribute expexts a name as argument getAttribute("class")

Comment: That's exactly my problem, there isn't any attribute to this text i'm trying to get, it's one line bellow from the one i'm making the Xpath.

Comment: Add that detail to your question to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just the last doubt, with this Xpath, how could i extract the text if it doesn't have any values?

Comment: you mean the element does not have attributes?

Comment: Yes, exactly, the element who does not have attributes

Comment: As in this xpath, refer to a parent element that has attributes or other unique caracteristic : `//div[@itemprop="description"]/p/text()`

Comment: My problem now is not exatly the Xpath, but it's how do i see the result? how do i print it? do i use .get_attribute and then print(variable)?

Comment: No, should be something like getValue or nodeValue. Try the xpath I suggested.

Comment: With the first worked. It was missing the end part (.text)     (By.XPATH, '//div[@itemprop="description"]').text